# Should ForeignKeyAttribute be used on naviation property or normal property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm wondering what the difference is between specifying the [ForeignKeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the navigation property or the regular property.

```
public int ParentId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ParentId")]
public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

versus

```
[ForeignKey("Parent")]
public int ParentId { get; set; }
public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

When used with code-first, I don't see a difference in the database that is created. Is one way better than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any mention of the second sample on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but XML documentation in the source code is more verbose and says:

> If placed on a foreign key property, the name of the associated navigation
>             property. If placed on a navigation property, the name of the associated
>             foreign key(s). If a navigation property has multiple foreign keys,
>             a comma separated list should be supplied.

So there shouldn't be any difference. But to me, the first option seems more natural.

Answer (score 1):

By convention it's seeing ParentId as the foreign key as it is the name of the entity followed by Id.

You should be able to do:

```
public int ParentId { get; set; }
public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

But agree with @Lukas-Kabrt that option 1 is the better of your 2 examples.